# Accessing individual pages within existing pdf using arcpy.mapping?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, pdf

I've used the arcpy.mapping module for some time now to create mapbooks and other pdf documents, using a combination of Data Driven Pages and Python. I would like to take an existing pdf and save each individual page as separate pdfs.

I have read through the online documentation for [`PDFDocument`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/PDFDocument/00s30000002w000000/), and while I can see the usefulness of the `pageCount` property, I don't see how I can access an individual page. The only reference I see to a page number is when using the `insertPages` method to insert a page before an existing page.

I know that using something like [`pypdf`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPDF2/1.18) enables one to iterate over the pages in a pdf and other useful things, but I'd like to know if I can do this using `arcpy` before downloading it.

Comment: It could be messy but if you can get a PDFDocument object, and the number of pages in it then you should be able to open a copy of that PDF file and delete all but one page using `deletePages (page_range)` once either side of the page you are interested in.

Comment: That would work but I agree that it would get messy. I just tried it with PyPDF2 and it worked brilliantly with little fuss, so I'll just integrate that into my arcpy script. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of 10.3.1, it is still not possible to do this using the arcpy.mapping module. Using other conventional Python libraries such as PyPDF2 seems to be the solution for now.

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
in_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(r'C:\Myfile.pdf', 'rb'))

for i in range(0, in_pdf.getNumPages()):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(in_pdf.getPage(i))
    output_stream = file(r'C:\Myfile_' + str(i+1) + '.pdf', 'wb')
    output.write(output_stream)
```

Comment: I think it is incorrect to say that you cannot do this with arcpy.mapping - see [my answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/214201/115) to this question.

Answer (score 0):

It will need a little code but with arcpy.mapping you can get a [PDFDocument](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/pdfdocument-class.htm) object, and the number of pages in it (`pageCount` property).

Consequently, you should be able to open a copy of that PDF file and delete all but one page using `deletePages` (`page_range`) with a range that can be specified either side of the page you are interested in.

Some code that I just wrote and tested successfully in ArcGIS 10.4.1 (I think it would have worked since 10.0) is below:

```
import arcpy

pdfPath = r"C:\Temp\test.pdf"
pdfDoc = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentOpen(pdfPath)
pageCount = pdfDoc.pageCount
pageList = []
for count in range(1,pageCount + 1):
    arcpy.Copy_management(pdfPath,pdfPath.replace("test","page"+str(count)))
    pageList.append(str(count))
del pdfDoc

print pageList

for count in range(1,pageCount + 1):
    print "Processing PDF for page {0} ...".format(count)
    pageDeleteList = list(pageList)
    pageDeleteList.remove(str(count))
    pages = ",".join(pageDeleteList)
    pdfDoc = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentOpen(pdfPath.replace("test","page"+str(count)))
    print "Deleting pages {0} ...".format(pages)
    pdfDoc.deletePages(pages)
    pdfDoc.saveAndClose()
    del pdfDoc
```

This will enable you to keep your installs and imports as simple as possible.

Comment: Yes, while it would be possible in arcpy, it certainly isn't the best way to do it, especially for something which is a non-GIS operation. I originally asked this question because I need to create new, individual mapbooks out of separated pages from an existing pdf document containing tables, along with their matching maps.